# How can I ignore cascade when calling persist/merge

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

How can I ignore cascade saving/updating when calling `persist(..)`/ `merge(..)` without removing cascade annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Two workarounds come to my mind:

- empty the collections before persisting
- use HQL to insert/update

Neither is a good option though.

Answer (score 1):

If you find you have two different use cases, one that makes using the save/update annotation useful, and one that makes it not useful, I'd create a second class, either using inheritance or simply a different class, depending on the complexity of your model. One mapping will omit the cascade annotation, to be used in those cases you don't want it to happen.